# Non-degenerate differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

I'm looking into symplectic forms which requires the differential 2-form to be closed and non-degenerate. I know that in Euclidean space, a differential 2-form $\omega:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is non-degenerate if $\omega(v,w)=0$ implies $w=0$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$.  However, what would it mean for a differential 2-form on a manifold to be non-degenerate?  Would it simply be the same definition but $\omega(v,w)=0$ implies $w=0$ for all $v\in M$ where M is the manifold?

Also, how do you show a 2-form is non-degenerate, for example, in the standard symplectic in $\mathbb{R}^2$, if $v=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b \end{pmatrix}$ and $w=\begin{pmatrix}c\\d \end{pmatrix}$ then for $\omega (v,w)=0$, $\omega(v,w)=ad-bc=0$ but why does that imply $c=d=0$?  Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Nondegeneracy (at a point $p\in M$) means that if $\omega_p(v,w)=0$ *for all choices of* $v\in T_pM$, then $w=0$.  In your example we have $ad-bc=0$ *for all choices of* $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.  Can you choose $a$ and $b$ in a way that shows $c=0$, and then choose other values which force $d=0$?

Comment: Note that the vectors that $\omega$ takes as arguments are *not* elements of $M$. A 2-form on a manifold is a function which takes, at every point of $M$, two vectors *from the tangent space at that point*, and outputs a real number. $M$ is not a vector space in general!

Comment: Another way to check non-degeneracy is computing the determinant of the matrix $\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Given a real vector space $V$, a bilinear form $\Omega:V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is non-degenerate if 
$\Omega(v,w)=0$ for all $w\in V$ implies $v=0$.

A differential $2$-form $\omega$ on a manifold $M$ gives at each point $p\in M$ a bilinear form on the tangent space $T_{p}M$:
$$\omega_{p}:T_{p}M\times T_{p}M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$$
We say that $\omega$ is non-degenerate if $\omega_{p}$ is non-degenerate for all $p\in M$.

As for the standard symplectic form $\Omega$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, assume that $v=(a,b)$ is such that $\Omega(v,w)=0$ for all $w\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$. This implies that
$$ad-bc=0$$
for all $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. In particular for $d=1$ and $c=0$, which yields $a=0$. Setting $d=0$ and $c=1$ gives $b=0$.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Where did you get that definition of a differential form on a manifold from? The definition I have of a differential form on a manifold is a pull-back of the transition function.

Comment: @rmak See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form, the paragraph "Intrinsic definitions".